# Device not detected in fastboot | REALME 3 PRO

Tags: adb, fastboot

I have device Realme 3 Pro. And I am trying to install TWRP. So, I downloaded In-depth test apk and got application reviewed. Then I booted into fastboot and device is not showing in device manager. I tried to add legacy device with google usb drivers. It said drivers installed but device starting failed. Error code 10.
[image: ADD LEGACY HARDWARE]

It detected corrupted adb interface. So, I again updated same drivers.
[image: UPDATED DRIVERS]

This time device popped up in other devices and showed an error icon. So, I again updated drivers for the device. It says drivers installation successful.
[image: DRIVERS UPDATE SUCCESSFULL]

But, when i double click on icon it shows no drivers are installed.
[image: NO DRIVERS INSTALLED]

No matter how many time i update the drivers it shows no drivers installed.

---

**Solutions tried**

1. resetted my PC
2. resetted my phone
3. tried various ADB drivers for Windows
4. tried various ADB drivers for Android interface
5. completely wiped my PC
6. re-installed Windows (clean install)
7. updated Windows
8. updated all drivers present in Windows
9. updated BIOS
10. updated my phone to latest version

NOTE: OEM unlocking is ON. And usb-debugging is on too.

Comment: The ADB driver is for ADB not for fastboot. For Fastboot you need the driver "Android bootloader Interface".

Comment: @Robert I tried to install the bootloader drivers as well while keeping my phone in fastboot. But, It just installs and second after when I click on phone icon it shows no drivers are installed. It gives same result for any driver.

Comment: windows driver signature enforcement

Comment: @alecxs Ofcourse I tried to install various bootloader drivers while keeping my phone in fastbootboot mode and connected with my PC.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71YAIw7_-kg

Answer (score -1):

you can access your phone with `fastboot` command.
try `fastboot devices` in cmd and it will show connected fastboot devices.
you can see full command list with `fastboot --help`

if you want to install twrp, you need to enter the command:

```
fastboot flash recovery <your twrp image file>
```

but i think you need to unlock your bootloader first.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Kindly read the question before answering